# Execute Python script from AutoIt

Tags: python, autoit

I have a Python (.py) file and need to execute it from AutoIt. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python scripts can be executed from command line. For a script called `myscript.py`, you can run it (assuming Python is installed) by typing:

```
python myscript.py
```

If you want to run `myscript.py` without having to prefix it by `python`, then set the path to the Python binary (e.g. `C:\Python27\Python.exe`) as Windows environment variable. This enables AutoIt to execute the Python script as if it were an external program. Reference: [`ShellExecute()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm).

```
ShellExecute("myscript.py")
```

Point to where `myscript.py` resides of course. Use:

```
RunWait("C:\Python27\Python.exe myscript.py")
```

to avoid setting environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
RunWait("C:\Python27\Python.exe filename.py")
```

this code working fine run from autoit