# Execute external program with command line arguments

Tags: python, autoit

I want to execute a Python script from AutoIt using [`ShellExecuteWait()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecuteWait.htm). My Attempt:

```
$x = ShellExecuteWait("E:/Automation/Python/Scripts/ReadLog.py", '-f "file.log" -k "key" -e "errMsg" ')
MsgBox(0,"x=",String($x))
If @error Then
    MsgBox(0,"Error=",String(@error))
EndIf
```

I can see some process id in `$x`, and `@error` also gets set to `0` (means AutoIt executed the script). But my Python script is not producing results (it writes to a txt file when executed independently). Seems the problem is with passing command line arguments like:

```
ShellExecuteWait("E:/Automation/Python/Scripts/ReadLog.py", '-f "file.log" -k "key" -e "errMsg" ')
```

How can I pass command line arguments using `ShellExecuteWait()`? Syntax:

> ShellExecuteWait ( "filename" [, "parameters" [, "workingdir" [,"verb" [, showflag]]]] )
>
> Parameters:
>
> filename   :- The name of the file to run (EXE, .txt, .lnk, etc).
>
> parameters :- [optional] Any parameters for the program. Blank ("") uses none.

This misses examples for use of parameters. There are no problems with the Python script (it requires 3 command line arguments, strings with options `-f`, `-k` and `-e`).

Related: [How to run or execute python file from autoit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524339/how-to-run-or-execute-python-file-from-autoit).

Comment: [Related](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/189963-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-programpython-from-runwait/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the path to your Python binary (e.g. Python.exe, wherever your Python program/binary is located) in your Window's system environment/path.

[Execute Python script from AutoIt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524339/how-to-run-or-execute-python-file-from-autoit) If path is there then your code must work. In `$x` you will receive return exit code of the Python script.

Also you can try:

```
RunWait('full_path\Python.exe ReadLog.py -f "file.log" -k "key" -e "errMsg"', 'full_path_of_working_directory')
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt does not execute external programs/scripts until you pass the working directory (optional parameter to all the execute and run commands). So pass the working directory as a separate parameter and it will work:

```
RunWait('full_path\Python.exe ReadLog.py -f "file.log" -k "key" -e "errMsg"', 'full_path_of_working_directory')
```